# Is it possible to use EEG Library for CSV to EDF

Tags: python, pandas, csv, european-data-format

I found this link (https://github.com/lsilva6851/EDF/blob/master/edf2csv.py), which converts EDF to CSV. How would one convert CSV to EDF?

Comment: Just changed some grammar and spelling.